# How to prove that in any finite graph, the number of vertices with odd degree is even

Tags: graph-theory

I am trying to solve problem described in the title.

### What I've tried

I tried to consider simple examples of graph with 0, 1 and 2 vertices and figured out that every edge has start node and end node, so number of edges can be calculated as follows:
**E** - number of edges in graph
**Nd** - degree of node
$$E=\frac{\sum Nd}{2}$$
Since number of edges must be integer, $\sum Nd$ must be even. It is only even if there is even number of odd sum components.

### Questions

**Is this enough to prove the conjecture?**
**Is there other way to prove that?**

Comment: Thats fine. The only thing you could elaborate a little more, is the last point you make, e.g. by looking at the equation $\mod 2$ and splitting of the nodes with even degree. But that's more a matter of "how super-rigoros do I want it to be?".

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE, the question is well written and follow MSE codes, but that's a very redundant question... https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181833/proving-that-the-number-of-vertices-of-odd-degree-in-any-graph-g-is-even?rq=1 
or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407250/the-number-of-odd-degree-vertices-is-even-in-a-finite-graph?rq=1
or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1760467/prove-that-graph-with-odd-number-of-odd-degree-vertices-does-not-exist?rq=1
or other I can't include because the comment is too long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, and this is a standard proof for this problem.

The handshaking lemma states that the sum of all degrees is 2 times the number of edges. But, this can be broken up into those vertices that have an even degree (call them $V_{even}$) and those that have an odd degree ($V_{odd}$). That is,

$$2E = \sum_{u \in V}deg(u) = \sum_{u \in V_{even}}deg(u) + \sum_{u \in V_{odd}}deg(u)$$.

Since the number of edges $E$ is an integer, then $2E$ is an even number. Also, the sum of degrees for all vertices with even degrees $\sum_{u \in V_{even}}deg(u)$ is an even number. So we have 
$$evenNumber = evenNumber + \sum_{u \in V_{odd}}deg(u)$$

Since the other elements are even, necessarily $\sum_{u \in V_{odd}}deg(u)$ is an even number, too. Which means there is an even number of elements with an odd degree because otherwise the sum would be an odd number.